# How do I get the contour right on a messy plant image?

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

I have many photos of random plants and I am trying to cut the biggest leaf from each photo. I am a NOOB at cutting things out using canny.

I have tried to employ an auto canny settings function but this still does not suffice. Any ideas people?

Edit:

original pic: (https://github.com/Usul1980/cut-leaves/blob/master/tomatoes.jpg)

output pic: (https://github.com/Usul1980/cut-leaves/blob/master/method1_output.jpg)

My reproducible code is here: https://github.com/Usul1980/cut-leaves/blob/master/leafcut.py

I was hoping it would cut the biggest leaf in the picture out neatly but it does not. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to refine the problem?

Comment: (1) Some examples of the images you're dealing with would be nice.  (2) If you can cut down the code so that it's a [mcve], that would help us in suggesting what to do next. (3) Unfortunately, your question as it is right now is currently off-topic.  Please see [ask].

Comment: I have posted the pics links thank you. The code is already at minimal reproducible point.